# AMCharts right-align column label text

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a rotated column chart and I want the column labels to all be right-aligned so that they appear centered on top of one another. Here is a JSFiddle of what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/pk1Lsyyw/. Here's a quick mockup of what I want it to look like:

[image: example]

I've tried using

```
graph.labelPosition = "right";
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas how I can get the labels to appear on the right side like that?

Comment: I have had a little look but cannot find a way of doing it.  If you raise a support ticket on amcharts web site they might look into it for future updates potentially.  They are very helpful and answered many of my questions in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by default, but you could add another graph to your chart, make it invisble and show the data of column graph in it's data labales.